# Wordpress does not charge my js files after webpack compilation

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I use webpack and babbel for my js files in my wordpress website.
I need help because, my css files are correctly charged by wordpress but not my js files and I don't know why.

The compilation works, the paths of the files are correct, it's just wordpress that doesn't load the js files.

Here my webpack.config.js :

```js
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        main: './src/index.js',
        bootstrap: './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js', 
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                  loader: 'babel-loader',
                  options: {
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                  }
                }
            } 
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'style.css'
        })
    ]
};
```

Here the code in functions.php :

```php
function theme_scripts() {

    // styles
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/style.css', ['bootstrap'] );

    // js
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/main.js', ['jquery'], wp_get_theme()->get('Version'), true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/bootstrap.js', ['jquery', 'main'], wp_get_theme()->get('Version'), true );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts' );
```

There are no errors in console and the files are not in "network" in my browser.

Comment: could be related to the order in which the scripts are being loaded. Specifically, the bootstrap script is being loaded after the main script, even though main depends on bootstrap.

Try changing the order in which the scripts are being enqueued in the theme_scripts() function:
`wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/bootstrap.js', ['jquery'], wp_get_theme()->get('Version'), true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/main.js', ['jquery', 'bootstrap'], wp_get_theme()->get('Version'), true );`

Comment: It does not change anything. In the console I have just the jquery script. I have not the bootsrtap script and not the main script...

Comment: It works when I put "false" instead of "true" to load my scripts not in the footer. But I don't understand why I can't load the scripts in the footer ?